# Textbook with exam questions and solutions all bundled together using exsheet

Tags: exam, books, exsheets

I would like to thank those who have edited my question, and thoae who had answered the previous post. I am trying to write a book with the following key features

1. Questions laid out in the `exam` class format with `question` number, `part` and `subpart`
2. Questions, question parts and subparts should indicate the number of marks or points as well as total points for the whole question such as `\addtotalpoints` in exam class
3. Solutions which will be written after the question during typesetting, but appearing at the end of the book.

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage{exsheets}  
\SetupExSheets{  
 counter-format=ch.qu,counter-within=chapter  
        }  

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block}{default}  
{  
join   = { title[r,B]number[l,B](1ex,0pt) } ,
attach =
{
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
},
above  = \baselineskip-.5ex ,
below  = .5ex}\NewQuSolPair{exercise}{solution}  

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myheadings2}{default}{  
   runin = true,  
   number-post-code = \space,}  

\SetupExSheets{  
question/pre-body-hook = {%  
\hyperlink{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{\underline{\textbf{Exercise:}   
            \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}}\par
},  
solution/pre-hook = {%    \hypertarget{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{}%
},
solution/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperref[qu:\CurrentQuestionID]{\underline{\textbf{Solution:} 
            \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}}\par
},
headings = myheadings2 }    


\section{Cell structure} 
\begin{itemize}
\item all living organisms are made up of cells
\item cells may be specialised to carry out a particular function
\item specialised cells include root hair cells, nerve cells, red blood cells
\end{itemize}  
\begin{exercise}  
\begin{enumerate}
\item[]
\item Which organelle is responsible for:
\begin{enumerate}
\item entry and exit of substances into or out of the cell
\item controlling all cellular activities  
\end{enumerate}
\item Below is a diagram of a plant cell.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Identify parts 1- 6.
\item Identify features which are \textbf{not} found in animal cells  
\end{enumerate}  
\end{enumerate}  
\end{exercise}  
\begin{solution} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[]
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item cell membrane
        \item nucleus
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{itemize}
            \item chloroplast
            \item permanent vacuole
            \item cytoplasm
            \item cell wall
            \item cell membrane
            \item nucleus
        \end{itemize}
        \item 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item chloroplast/1
            \item permanent vacuole/2
            \item cell wall/4
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}  
\end{solution}  
\chapter{Nutrition}
\section{Diet}\index{Diet}
\begin{itemize}  
\item living organisms need food for the following:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  to produce energy that is used in work and physical exercise and to keep the body temperature at $37^OC$
    \item for growth
    \item to renew and repair worn out tissues
\end{enumerate}  
\end{itemize}
\begin{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item A person’s diet should contain carbohydrate and fat and protein.  Give two reasons why.
    \item Name one health problem, other than being overweight, that is linked to an unbalanced diet.
\end{enumerate}

\item Explain the importance of the following in maintaining good health
\begin{enumerate}
    \item personal hygiene
    \item sewage disposal
\end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item   
\begin{itemize}
    \item  to get a balanced diet / to prevent malnourishment
    \item to obtain energy
    \item  for  building cells / growth / repair
\end{itemize}
\item heart disease, any deficiency disease
\end{enumerate}

\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item prevent the spread of diseases
\item prevent the spread of diseases
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} 

\end{question}
\chapter{Answers}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but you can't use the `exam` class since you use `book`. Recreating the items you want is hard work. The `exam` class doesn't typeset the solutions at the end, but underneath the question. The best I came up with is using an `enumerate` and label all `\item`s and then type all the solutions at the end of the document.

Comment: I find lists too restrictive, especially w.r.t. \hangindent.  I use \makebox and \parbox instead.  As for moving the solutions to the end, one way is to create a new float class and use endfloat.  Personally, I would accumulate them in a savebox (\vbox).

Answer (score 3):

This shows how to format titles using `\makebox` etc.  It also shows how to accumulate solutions in a savebox.

Once you are satisfied with the formatting, you can create exercise and solution environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 

\newsavebox{\solutions}
\setbox\solutions=\vbox{}

\newsavebox{\titlebox}
\newcounter{exercise}

\begin{document}
\section{Cell structure}
\begin{itemize} 
\item all living organisms are made up of cells 
\item cells may be specialised to carry out a particular function 
\item specialised cells include root hair cells, nerve cells, red blood cells 
\end{itemize}

\sbox\titlebox{\refstepcounter{exercise}% to avoid writing it twice
\makebox[1in][l]{\normalfont\bfseries Exercise~\theexercise}%
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \columnwidth-1.5in-\columnsep}{\normalfont Fill in the missing words.}\hfill
\makebox[0.5in][l]{\normalfont 10 points}}%

\noindent\usebox\titlebox
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        Animals cells contain $..............$, a semi-fluid solution of salts and other molecules, and are surrounded by a $..............$. When surrounded by distilled water, the animal cells absorb water by $..............$. 
    \item   The leaves of green plants obtain the gas $..............$ which they require for photosynthesis, by a process of $..............$. They also lose the gas oxygen produced during $..............$ by the same process. These gases move in and out through small pores called $..............$.
    \item Water is obtained by plants from the soil solution. The water enters by the process of $..............$, via structures outside the root called $..............$.  Water is transported in the $..............$. Sugars produced during photosynthesis are transported in the $..............$    
    \end{enumerate}

\setbox\solutions=\vbox{\unvbox\solutions
\noindent\usebox\titlebox
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item a cytoplasm
            \item cell membrane
            \item osmosis
        \end{itemize}
    \item
      \begin{itemize}
        \item carbon dioxide 
        \item diffusion
        \item photosynthesis
        \item stomata
      \end{itemize}
    \item 
      \begin{itemize}
        \item osmosis
        \item root hair cells
        \item xylem
        \item phloem
      \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\par}%

\chapter{Solutions}
  \unvbox\solutions
\end{document}
```